# On a combination between an equivalence to the Riemann's Hypothesis and the abc conjecture

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, totient-function, conjectures, primorial

If my calculations were rights, it's easy to deduce combining the abc conjecture with Nicolas equivalence to the Riemann's Hypothesis that:

$\qquad\qquad\forall \epsilon>0$ there exists a positive constant $C=C(\epsilon)$ such that $$e^{\gamma}\log \log (N_k\mathcal{N}_k)<\frac{N_k\left(C(\epsilon)\cdot\operatorname{rad}(abc)^{1+\epsilon}-N_k\right)}{\varphi(N_k\mathcal{N}_k)}.$$
Here I am denoting by $a\equiv a_k=N_k$ the primorial of order $k$, and $b\equiv b_k$ (now we are omiting the subscripts $k$ for the variables $a,b$ and $c$), $b=\mathcal{N}_k=\prod_{j=k+1}^{2k}p_j$ with $p_j$ the jth prime number (I choose this definition for $b's$ by symmetry, but one can do different definitions for $b$ as coprime with $a$, I don't know what's can to be more interesting that mine), and $$c=a+b,$$ and thus with $\varphi(n)$ the Euler totient function, $\operatorname{rad}(n)$ the [radical of an integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer) $n\geq 1$ and $\gamma$ the Euler Mascheroni constant.

I believe that these simple calculations were rigths, and I am interested if it's possible do more calculations, I say easy deduction to study such inequality.

> **Question.** A) What's about an unconditional lower bound (I believe that this is the interesting bound, the lower) of $$\operatorname{rad}\left(N_k\mathcal{N}_k(N_k+\mathcal{N}_k)\right)?$$
>   If this was in the literature provide us information about the references. Can you deduce some about it?
>
> B) And what's about a more general study of the inequality? I am asking about more calculations involving the Euler totient function, and the logarithms in LHS with the purpose to study the veracity of our inequality for integers  $k\geq 1$. **Many thanks.**

---

References: One can find Nicolas statement in this [Wikipedia, subsection 3.7.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis), or in his paper Nicolas, *Petites valeurs de la fonction d’Euler*, J. Number Theory 17 (1983), no. 3. And the statement for the abc conjecture is for example is in the first paragraph of  this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/abcConjecture.html) (I say for positive integers in our triples to avoid the absolute values).

Comment: Even after 8 years there is no answer here, why? The question is understandable enough and no edit has been requested yet to make it more clear and concise.